# Soundcloud embedded HTML5 player - How to turn off "Play another track"?

Tags: html5-audio, soundcloud

I am embedding as follows:

```
<iframe width="700px" height="166" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F108969529&amp;auto_play=false&amp;show_artwork=false&amp;show_user=false&amp;show_playcount=false&amp;color=ff7700"></iframe>
```

When It's done playing, it asks if the user wants to play another track that isn't even mine.  I would like to disable this feature, or, at least, constrain it to only my tracks.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Might be better to contact [SoundCloud Support](http://help.soundcloud.com) about this. I'm not sure there's an option for this.

Comment: Did you find a solution? This renders SoundCloud basically unusable for a research project website, because it will tell visitors to play random bullshit tracks which are entirely unrelated to our contents. If this thing cannot be deactivated, I will simply host the mp3 files myself. Can't think why they would be so nasty about it.

Answer (score 0):

FYI I contacted SoundCloud Support about this same issue and was told I needed to upgrade to Pro Unlimited (their most expensive paid plan) to turn off the "play more tracks" feature.

Answer (score -1):

In order to do this for free set all your tracks to private...